# RabbitMQ resend message to failed consumer only

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue

If I publish a message to an exchange and a consumer of the message fails to process it I can retry the message at a set interval. The problem is the message gets sent to all consumers instead of just the consumer which failed.

How do you only resend the message to the consumer which failed?

Comment: When you say sent a message to Exchange then what type of exchange it is ? And do you have one queue per consumer and message gets published to all of them ? Can you ask a bit in detail ?

Comment: The exchange is a topic exchange. Each consumer has their own queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If consumer fails, then the message will stay in the queue and you dont have to send it again. When the consumer is up and running you will receive the last message that it failed to process. That way we solve the problem of sending the message over and over again. And you don't have to send a `Nack` just dont `Ack` the message and the message will be in the queue when the consumer fails. You can try that by getting the message and stopping the consumer before doing `Ack`. You will be able to see the message again in the queue.

Answer (score 0):

suppose you have and exchange bound to more queues

```
exchange ---> queue1 ---> consumer 1 
        |---> queue2 ---> consumer 2
        |---> queue3 ---> consumer 3
```

if one consumer fails, you don't need to re-send the message, the message is stored to the queue. That's the scope to have queues

Comment: If consumer 2 fails I want to resend the message only to consumer 2 in 5 minutes. How would you do this?

Comment: I believe you don't have to resend the message if the consumer fails, dont Ack the message. After the consumer is completely done with processing then only Ack the message so it will get deleted. With Rabbitmq you can handle this on the consumer side and not on the publisher side. 
If the consumer fails to process the message, it will stay in queue and consumer will get the message again when its up .

Comment: @tibanez you don't have to resend the message. as Mitra Ghorpade says, it is enough to use manual ack. If the consumer fails, does not send the ack. I want to add that you always publish to an exchange and you always consume to one or more queues.

Comment: @MitraGhorpade I see I can send a `nack` and tell it to requeue the message but that just keeps on sending the message over and over again. I would like to resend the message every 5 minutes.

Comment: @Gabriele Not sending an ack means it's still in the queue but it does not get sent again unless I explicitly send a nack with the requeue option to true but this causes the problem I mentioned above.

Comment: I think if say your consumer fails, then the message will stay in the queue and you dont have to send it again. When the consumer is up and running you will receive the last message that it failed to process. That way we solve the problem of sending the message over and over again. 

And you dont have to send a Nack just dont Ack the message and the message will be in the queue when the consumer fails. You can try that by getting the message and stopping the consumer before doing Ack. You will be able to see the message again in the queue.

Comment: @MitraGhorpade Ah yes I see. My queue was exclusive so once the connection went it was deleted but it's working now. Thanks!

Comment: Is it ok if I make the comment as my answer and you can accept that so people can see the Exact answer for the question you asked ?